# ExpressJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token C

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, express

I am trying to save my string to a comma separated array, but when I try to use the `JSON.parse` method, I receive this error upon sending a post method and trying to save a record:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c
   at Object.parse (native)
   at router.route.post.get.res.render.blogpost (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/app/routes.js:106:34)
```

Here is my route (error coming at blogpost.save):

```
router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.featureImage = req.body.featureImage; // set the blog image
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = JSON.parse(req.body.tags.split(",")); // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method


        .get(isLoggedIn, function(req, res, blogpost) {
            res.render('pages/blogpost-create', {
              blogpost : blogpost
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JSON.parse` parses a string (of valid JSON) into an object/array.

You already have an array, as you're doing

```
req.body.tags.split(",")
```

and `split()` creates an array. You can't parse an array, but you could stringify it

Comment: Hey @adeneo thank you for your help so far, I left it with the split method, but I'm noticing that my values are being displayed as links for individual characters and not words. Does this have to do with how I'm saving the values?

Comment: `<% for(var i=0; i<blogpost.tags.length; i++) { %>
    <a href="/tag/<%= blogpost.tags[i] %>"><%= blogpost.tags[i] %></a>
    <% } %>`

Comment: @cphill - I don't know? Now it looks like you're on to EJS or something, and you should probably ask a new question regarding this, but if you're getting individual characters, you're iterating over a string, not an array, which makes sense if you removed the `split()`, maybe you should've removed the outer `JSON.parse` instead and just kept the array